# ANTLR How to distinguish terminal from regex

Tags: antlr

Consider the following simplified grammar:

```
ID  :   ('a'..'z') ('a'..'z')*;

TYPE    :   'int' '[' ']' |
        'boolean' |
        'int';
```

Now if I write *boolean* as input, it can be parsed as *ID* or as *TYPE*. I want it to be parsed as *TYPE* - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `TYPE` *before* `ID`:

```
TYPE : 'int' '[' ']' 
     | 'boolean' 
     | 'int'
     ;

ID   : ('a'..'z') ('a'..'z')*
     ;
```

ANTLR's lexer rules work like this:

1. match as much as possible
2. if after rule #1, two or more rules match the same amount of characters, pick the rule defined first in the grammar

Because of these rules, `"boolean"` is tokenized as `TYPE`, while `"booleans"` would be tokenized as `ID` <sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> `"booleans"` is *not* tokenized as two tokens: `TYPE` (`"boolean"`) and an `ID` (`"s"`))